# Automatically georeference non-intersecting UAS photos based on contained EXIF metadata

Tags: georeferencing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, orthophoto, photogrammetry, exif

I need to know how to **automatically** create georeferenced rasters from multiple non-intersecting photos taken by UAS DJI Phantom 4 Pro. 
All EXIF metadata is present in every photo - coordinates, height, camera angles (yaw, pitch, roll). Here is [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wXH3eeeFOCNzSO02gnbUzhXMMs8Vx3jN), with EXIF metadata.

I uploaded some photos, which I need to georeference: [Photo 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12tZLmFe_P7c959CInAkp4Rgkl2pU0QvU/view), [Photo 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11LBlV8_OTvLbc8OSUwtuMI2quqphk1ow/view), [Photo 3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14nBk_osIVnvNQoNaOD_CwnDP6Lt3KDT5/view).

Theses photos do not intersect, so it is impossible to create orthopoto with automated photogrammetry software (e.g. Agisoft Photoscan, Pix4D Mapper, Trimble INPHO). Of course, I can georeference these photos manually in desktop GIS based on underlying satellite imagery, but it is not feasible due to large number of images and time constraints.

We regularly perform monitoring flights over rivers and open water areas and take number of non-intersecting images when we observe species of interest. We need to quickly georeference these images for subsequent use as a layer in GIS for further analysis.

I realize, that this is not standard UAS scenario, but I hope there will be solution. We do not need precise georefencing, just a tough one will suffice.

I have seen something similar done with MISB-compliant video for UAS by means "Full-Motion Video" Plugin for ArcGIS.  MISB-compliant video has coordinates and camera orientation parameters which Full-Motion Video Plugin utilizes for georeferencing any single video frames: [Full Motion Video (FMV) ArcMap (by Esri)](https://youtu.be/R5x57d2tOQE?t=148).

So, I am looking for something similar for UAS photos.

Comment: Have you tried ArcGIS Pro's [Auto Georeference tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/georeferencing-a-raster-automatically-to-another-raster.htm)?  In any event, this looks like you are seeking a software recommendation for which there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: This Esri tool is not helpful, unfortunately. 
With all due respect, very many questions on this forum are much more software related compared to mine. Almost no chance to have my very narrow question answered outside of this forum.

Comment: Do you need to have the images orthorectified? 
Tools are available to create point data from EXIF so you can see the image location in a GIS and then open the image. 
 These images will not be tilted or rotated. 
 Agisoft published a script that will generate footprints from images. 
 Maybe just align the images in Agisoft, and export the footprints. 
 Script from there.  I do not access to Agisoft during the quarantine or I would try it for you.   Also see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340301/determining-longitude-and-latitude-of-each-corner-of-image/340303#340303

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I do need images orthorectified, so that I can use them as a base layer. Very rough orthorectification will suffice.

"Tools are available to create point data from EXIF so you can see the image location in a GIS and then open the image." - I did this in Global Mapper, it automatically reads coordinates from UAS photo and creates vector point, referencing particukar photo. Again, it is useful, but not sufficient for my goals.

"Agisoft published a script that will generate footprints from images" - polygon or point type of footprint?

Comment: Agisoft image footprint, yes.  See this link:  https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=6662.0

Comment: @GBG
Thank you for your kind response. However, https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=6662.0 says "The following script should be creating the shape layer with the footprints related to the ALIGNED cameras."
My cameras (i.e. photos) can not be aligned in Agsoft as they are non-intersecting (single photo for particular area without any overlap with others).

Comment: I am developing these tool now but I am not ready to share code.  I can automatically georeference P4P images but there are some assumptions like the plane upon which the georeferencing happens is flat and the height above the ground is consistent.  The final georeferening is close but not 'perfect'.  If you want to provide a link to your files I can test my code against your images.